# Hide method is working but not disable in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using `<a>` attribute on which `hide()` is working but not `disable` can anyone let me know why.

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sohampshetty/pdaubf13/)

```js
$("#1").click(function() {
  if (!$(".id_" + event.target.id).hasClass('minus-symbol')) {
    alert('data')
    var id = event.target.id
    $(".id_" + event.target.id).removeClass('plus-symbol').addClass('minus-symbol')
      //$(".id_"+event.target.id).hide(); // hide is working
    $(".id_" + id).attr('disabled', true); // disable is not working  
  } else {
    alert('data1')
    $(".id_" + event.target.id).addClass('plus-symbol').removeClass('minus-symbol')
  }
});
```

```css
.plus-symbol {
  background-image: url('../plus-sym.gif');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  padding-left: 7px;
}
.minus-symbol {
  background-image: url('../minus-symbol.gif');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  padding-left: 7px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class='plus-symbol id_1' id="1">data</a>
```

What a solution without changing `<a>` attribute.

Comment: The `disabled` property only works on form elements. If you want to stop the link from being clicked you need to change the `src`, remove the click handler or stop it from receiving mouse events.

Comment: @AndrewBone no its not working its not disabling the attribute `<a>`. when you inspect it will show disabled.

Comment: disable is for form controls, it stops data input to the control or any action (button click). If you want the link to be disabled, you need to add e.preventDefault() to the click event function so it looks like `$("#1").click(function(e ){ e.preventDefault() ....}`

Comment: _when you inspect it will show disabled_ That is the property of form elements other elements can't have this property.

Comment: Well @phooey, But i want to enable it after ajax call completion

Comment: @phooey There is no default behaviour for click event on  anchor without href attribute specified

Comment: If you set attribute `disabled` (like you do in your code but usually shouldn't), not the property which isn't mapped with relevant attribute for anchor tag, you can use [pointer-events](http://caniuse.com/#feat=pointer-events): `a[disabled] {
    pointer-events: none;
    opacity: .5;
}`    http://jsfiddle.net/oh02xhm0/

Comment: Hi All, Can you tell Administrator That this not **Off topic** Question.

Comment: @SohamShetty: just put a data attribute on the link when you finished loading the data - `$("#1").data("loaded",true)`. Now within your click event then check if it exists, if so use e.preventDefault();

Comment: @SohamShetty You have to provide MCVE, your posted code isn't only relevant to your issue

Comment: @A.Wolff Fiddle is showing issue.

Comment: @SohamShetty check my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like guys mentioned in comment the `disabled` property only works on form elements. You can disable click using a global boolean variable e.g `clickable` and you can control click from it :

```js
var clickable=true;

$("#disable-click").click(function(){
    clickable=false;
});

$("#enable-click").click(function(){
    clickable=true;
});

$("#1").click(function(){

   if (clickable){
       if(!$(".id_"+event.target.id).hasClass('minus-symbol')){
          alert('data')
          var id = event.target.id
          $(".id_"+event.target.id).removeClass('plus-symbol').addClass('minus-symbol')
          //$(".id_"+event.target.id).hide(); // hide is working
       }else{
          alert('data1')
          $(".id_"+event.target.id).addClass('plus-symbol').removeClass('minus-symbol')
       }
   }
});
```

```css
.plus-symbol {
  background-image: url('../plus-sym.gif');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  padding-left: 7px;
}
.minus-symbol {
  background-image: url('../minus-symbol.gif');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  padding-left: 7px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class='plus-symbol id_1' id="1">data</a><br><br>
<button type="button" id='disable-click'>Disable Click</a>
<button type="button" id='enable-click'>Enable Click</a>
```

Comment: Yes. This is Good Workaround.

Answer (score 0):

The `disabled` behavior has nothing to do with JavaScript. It will be still clickable. You may try something like removing the `id` from `<a>` so that it wont trigger any more JS events. Something like;

```
removeAttr("id")
```

Give it a try.

Also, try;

```
$("#1").click(function(){
   if(!$(this).hasClass('minus-symbol')){
      alert('data');
      $(this).removeClass('plus-symbol').addClass('minus-symbol').attr('disabled','true').hide();
   }else{
      alert('data1');
      $(this).addClass('plus-symbol').removeClass('minus-symbol');
   }
});
```

Comment: I looking to enable it later.

Comment: you can use  $(".id_"+id).attr('disabled', true).off('click');